# how do i make website native android and ios?

Tags: android, web, webview, apk

Some websites can output the website we want to be converted as android apk. I don't understand how he does this. It can return the apk output after what processes it goes through in the background. I think this process is done with webview.

Does it require a server-side action or is it done with an api? This question really bothers me. What do I need to know in order to make such a website?
Also, how is licensing done?

screenshots of the sample site I want to make: gonative.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlqt0.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu45k.png)

Comment: After the user writes the site he wants, he clicks the button and has an apk in the form of an output. What is running in the background and can it do this?

Comment: If you could provide some more details on the objective, maybe a screenshot, it will clarify what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for PWAs (Progressive Web Apps)
PWAs can be used as installed applications
[Learn Here](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/#i18n.paths.progressive_web_apps.topics.make_it_installable)

Once installed, OS creates an icon for the application and launches the website in a headerless browser

If you have a website, you will need to add Progressive Web App support to it, the tools depend on the stack the website it is built on

For example, if it is built using Angular you will be working with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about websites that also are available as app for Android or iOS? As User @mhsarosh already mentioned, those are most probably Progressive Web Apps (PWA). To bundle them for mobile operating systems, a framework like [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/web/progressive-web-apps) can be used, which provides the interface to the smartphone OS.

Some of those websites provide a direct link to the app store, this might be what you call "some websites can output the website as an apk".

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you are possible talking about is the feature of mobile browsers like Firefox, that allow to "add website to home screen". This will create an app icon for the respective website and launch the website like an app, but this will just open a stripped down version of the browser.